# Adding API key for node in Taquito

Tags: taquito

How do i add an API key for my rpc in set provider? I could not find the apiKey parameter in the document
https://tezostaquito.io/typedoc/classes/_taquito_rpc.rpcclient.html

Comment: I am not sure I understand what you are trying to do, did you try passing the API key in the RPC link like that: `https://my_rpc_address.com?key=my_api_key` (with the right syntax for your API)?

Comment: I need to pass API key through headers for the rpc endpoint to work, will try this